# Vue3 transform props structure maintaining reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props, vue-reactivity

I have a component that gets data from the API and passes it to another component that displays it (passing down again to multiple child components). So I tried to split that information into multiple ref objects for passing down to each child component.

The problem is, doing that I loose reactivity... the new ref object does not update when parent component changes their data.

I created an example to show the problem.

`ParentComponent`

```html
<template>
  <p>All data: {{ data }}</p>
  <child-component :data="data"></child-component>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.vue";

let data = ref({
  a: {},
  b: {},
  c: {}, // More properties...
});

setTimeout(() => { // FAKE API
  data.value.a = {
    name: "prop A",
    description: "aaa"
  };
  data.value.b = {
    name: "prop B",
    description: "bbb"
  };
  data.value.c = {
    name: "prop C",
    description: "ccc"
  };
  // More properties updated...
}, 2000);
</script>
```

`ChildComponent`

```html
<template>
  <p>child component props: {{data}}</p>
  <p>child component manipulated: {{manipulated}}</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(['data'])

let manipulated = ref({ // Only need a and b properties.
  a: props.data.a,
  b: props.data.b
})

</script>
```

Output when mount components

```
All data: { "a": {}, "b": {}, "c": {} }

child component props: { "a": {}, "b": {}, "c": {} }

child component manipulated: { "a": {}, "b": {} }
```

Output after updated parent component data:

```
All data: { "a": { "name": "prop A", "description": "aaa" }, "b": { "name": "prop B", "description": "bbb" }, "c": { "name": "prop C", "description": "ccc" } }

child component props: { "a": { "name": "prop A", "description": "aaa" }, "b": { "name": "prop B", "description": "bbb" }, "c": { "name": "prop C", "description": "ccc" } }

child component manipulated: { "a": {}, "b": {} }
```

Desired result after updated parent component data:

```
All data: { "a": { "name": "prop A", "description": "aaa" }, "b": { "name": "prop B", "description": "bbb" }, "c": { "name": "prop C", "description": "ccc" } }

child component props: { "a": { "name": "prop A", "description": "aaa" }, "b": { "name": "prop B", "description": "bbb" }, "c": { "name": "prop C", "description": "ccc" } }

child component manipulated: { "a": { "name": "prop A", "description": "aaa" }, "b": { "name": "prop B", "description": "bbb" } }
```

How can achieve that? With primitives works... but with objects there is missing something to maintain the reactivity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use deep watcher

You could use a [deep watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) (i.e., [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) with the `deep` flag) on `props.data` that updates `manipulated` with the new values of `props.data`:

```js
// ChildComponent.vue
import { watch } from 'vue'
⋮
watch(
  () => props.data,
  newValue => {
    const { a, b } = newValue
    manipulated.value = { a, b }
  },
  { deep: true }
)
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-ref-when-prop-changes?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FChildComponent.vue)

#### Option 2: Use `computed`

If `manipulated` were just a read-only prop, you could switch from the `ref` and `watch` to a [`computed`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed) instead:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['data'])

let manipulated = computed(() => ({
  a: props.data.a,
  b: props.data.b,
}))
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-ref-when-prop-changes-ehirn4?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FChildComponent.vue)

Comment: Thank you, working fine! But why is it necessary to watch props? It is not obvious that I want it to be reactive? It is only necessary with objects, right? Still I think by default it should watch props

Comment: It seems you assume that `ref` initializations are reactively updated, but that's not the case. You would need `computed` for that, as shown in demo 2 above. Otherwise, you would need a watcher to update the `ref` when the prop changes.